# I would like to pass a 2d array of values to a second view in a Swift Single-View Application

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I am trying to create a basic sudoku solver using Xcode. Currently, I have a 9x9 display of text fields that gets converted to a 2d array and goes through a solver I've made already. My current dilemma is that I want to pass the solved array to a second view and print it to look like a sudoku board but I'm not sure how to 1.) correctly transition to the second view and 2.) how to bring the array with to print it.

I can't yet add images, but my Storyboard contains just two views. They are not connected currently. The first has the 9x9 display of text fields and a button beneath it with no action associated. The second has a 9x9 display of labels and nothing else.

Here is the entirety of the code for the first view:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var row1: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet var row2: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet var row3: [UITextField]!

@IBOutlet var row4: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet var row5: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet var row6: [UITextField]!

@IBOutlet var row7: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet var row8: [UITextField]!
@IBOutlet var row9: [UITextField]!


@IBAction func executeSolver() {
    var board = [[Int]](count: 9, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 9, repeatedValue: 0))
    var board2 = [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9]

    for var row = 0; row < 9; ++row{
        var rowE = board2[row];
        for var col = 0; col < 9; ++col{
            var val = rowE[col].text;

            if var intVal = val.toInt() {
                if intVal > 0 && intVal < 10 {
                    board[row][col] = intVal;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    var ss = Solver(givenBoard: board)
    board = ss.getBoard()

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Essentially I believe you are asking: How do I pass data between storyboard view controllers.  Are you able to connect your two view controllers with a segue?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a custom 2D struct.

Why would you use this? It gives you subscripting.
Also, if your labels share common characteristics, it might be wise to use an array of outlets and use tags to identify each instead of creating of outlets one by one.

```
struct Array2D<T> {
      let columns: Int
      let rows: Int
      private var array: Array<T?>

    init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
        self.columns = columns
        self.rows = rows
        array = Array<T?>(count: rows*columns, repeatedValue: nil)
    }

    subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
        get {
            return array[row*columns + column]
        }
        set {
            array[row*columns + column] = newValue
        }
    }
 }
```